# javascript horizontal menu click to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to make javascript horizontal menu, but can't get second button to open its own items, (when i click the second button it opens the items that are for the first button) here is current code:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-button,.menu-button1").click(function() {
    $(".menu-bar").toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li title="home"><a href="#" class="menu-button home">menu</a></li>
  <li title="pencil"><a href="#" class="menu-button1 pencil">pencil</a></li>
  <li title="about"><a href="#" class="active about">about</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu0</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home2000</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-button1">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please creare a jsfiddle.It will be easy to understand

Comment: can you please post CSS also?

Comment: View the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/1pjbnnya/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start my answer, let me explain jQuery a bit.

```
$(".menu-button,.menu-button1").click(function() {
  $(".menu-bar").toggleClass("open");
});
```

This broken down:

- `$(".menu-button,.menu-button1").click(function() {` -> When any item with class menu-button OR class menu-button1 is clicked
- `$(".menu-bar").toggleClass("open");` ->Toggle the "open" class for **all** elements in your page with class menu-bar.

Since you call all the menus instead of the specific one you want, it opens both of them.

So, be more specific by - for starters - using IDs, or unique/identifying classes:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-button.home").click(function() {
    $(".menu-bar.home").toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".menu-button.pencil").click(function() {
    $(".menu-bar.pencil").toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li title="home"><a href="#" class="menu-button home">menu</a></li>
  <li title="pencil"><a href="#" class="menu-button pencil">pencil</a></li>
  <li title="about"><a href="#" class="active about">about</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-bar home">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu0</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home2000</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-bar pencil">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-button1">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with M.Doye's comment about using .each (but sorry, I can't answer directly).

I want to add that, it will be much easier with that kind of HTML structure I think:

```
<ul class="menu">

  <li title="home">
     <a href="#" class="menu-button">Show Menu 1</a>
     <ul class="menu-bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu1 </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li title="pencil">
    <a href="#" class="menu-button">Show Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="menu-bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu2 </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

The, click on the link and use .next() or .siblings or closest... to show the right ul.
But of course you'll have to rewrite you CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-button,.menu-button1").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".menu-bar").toggleClass("open");
    })
})

<ul class="menu">
  <li title="home"><a href="#" class="menu-button home">menu</a>
    <ul class="menu-bar">
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="pencil"><a href="#" class="menu-button1 pencil">pencil</a>
    <ul class="menu-bar">
      <li><a href="#">Menu0</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home2000</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pjbnnya/12/)